# SHOW DATABASES command fails

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

When I run this command

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'information_schema./tmp/#sql_2569_0' doesn't exist
```

Any thoughts or ideas? I've tried rerunning the mysql-db-install scripts but no luck.

Comment: Try running [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-upgrade.html)?

Comment: check disk space, file permissions.

Comment: In every mysql installation there is schema called **information_schema**

May be your user don't have permission to access that or may be mysql user is unable to access file.

Comment: I have the right user permissions, I've double checked, and disk space is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had compiled the InnoDB storage engine statically and disabled the HEAP storage engine. The information_schema table is an in-memory table and therefore requires the HEAP storage engine.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good bug. The `information_schema` tables are utterly reliant on in-memory temporary tables, so realistically `information_schema` should be disabled if `HEAP` is disabled. Or, more realistically, the option to disable `HEAP` should just be removed. These days many `SHOW` commands are internally mapped to `information_schema` queries, so really a server without `HEAP` could be useless.

Comment: What MySQL version was this?

Answer (score 0):

check the following

1.my.cnf for skip_show_databses (deactivate it if present)

2.check for file permissions on your data directory ( 644 is good level )

3.if above two failed upgrade your mysql

4.In worst case you just create the directory and give  full permission to it and restart server ( it may work i am not sure but be careful and don't forget to take backup before you proceed)